# Setting `android:theme` on View (ThemeAttrAndroid?)

Tags: android, react-native

In my Android app. Some screens are "darkish" themed. So i need to apply a different `colorAccent` `colorPrimary` `colorDark` on them.

Per article - https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH - we can set `android:theme` and it and the descendents will get this.

So I have created multiple themes in my `styles.xml`, and am now trying to apply this to different `View`s or `TextInput`s per this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49172034/1828637

#### My goal (psuedo code)

In my `styles.xml` I have created two different themes, one for the dark screens, and one for the light screens:

```
<style name="EditTextTheme1" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent1</item>
</style>

<style name="SecondTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccent</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent2</item>
</style>
```

My goal is to now do this when on dark screen

```
<TextInput android:theme="EditTextTheme1" />
```

And then when on light screens I want to do this:

```
<TextInput android:theme="SecondTheme" />
```

Or apply it via a `View` like this:

```
<View android:theme="EditTextTheme1">
      <TextInput />
</View>

<View android:theme="SecondTheme">
      <TextInput />
</View>
```

#### What I tried

I have not been able to figure out how to apply `android:theme`. I even tried modifying native code - [Modifying ReactEditText.java is not taking affect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422582/modifying-reactedittext-java-is-not-taking-affect) . It seems `View` and `TextInput` etc do not have this `android:theme` prop. Does anyone know if there is a way to apply `android:theme` to a `View` so its children take this custom theme?

The closest I found was I found a `ThemeAttrAndroid` property in `TouchableNativeFeedback` - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b7bb2e5745f2bdbfeeccef8d97d469730942e01c/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableNativeFeedback.android.js#L108 - but I can't figure out how to use this to style descendents. I feel I'm very close.

Comment: Did you set your theme on Manifest ?? In ```Manifest```, ```<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="Your personal Theme> ... </activity>```

Comment: @TyeolRik yes I set custom themes in `styles.xml` like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49172034/1828637 - however I need to apply these custom themes to different text input elements.

Comment: I am not sure what your "Final" Goal (Sorry for lack English). Do you want to set 2 EditText which are different theme? (I mean, you have 2 EditText and both have different Cursor color, line or something which has relationship with theme)

Comment: No problem @TyeolRik I really appreciate it. I have created two themes. I will add it to the topic and let you know.

Comment: @TyeolRik I added to the topic "my goal" section. And "what i tried" section.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733171/7105963](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733171/7105963) How about watching this article? You can use ```getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_<whatever>, true);```. Actually, I am developing **Theme.AppCompat.DayNight** which has 2 modes and I am set modes programtically within 1 line. I am not sure whether this is "Right solution", But I think this could be an solution.

Comment: Thanks @TyeolRik - but doesn't this change the theme for the whole app? I need the whole app to be a one theme permanently. I just need some "TextInput"s to use a different theme.

Comment: Sorry for late comments (because of work :/) I don't know how to make but, there is **Theme.AppCompat.DayNight** which has 2 themes Light theme and Night theme. And you can switch it by using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35669650/7105963).

Comment: This link means you can change whole app theme (Actually not changing theme but switching 2 modes. so User thinks "Oh, theme could be changed with just 1 button".) ```getDelegate().applyDayNight();```

Comment: Thanks @TyeolRik - i actually can't use that method, because on one screen I need to have some methods that are using "dark" theme and some elements that are using "light" theme.